# Duda con precisión y redondeo de números reales

Tags: java

Tengo este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d1 = 2.3;
        System.out.println(d1*d1);
        System.out.println(2F/3);
}
```

El resultado es:

```
5.289999999999999
0.6666667
```

¿Por qué en el primero tiene esa precisión y en el segundo es menor?
Y en el segundo caso ¿Cómo hace el redondeo para que el último dígito sea 7?

Gracias anticipadas

Answer (score 0):

En el primer print estás haciendo d1*d1, que da como resultado un double, que tiene ese número de decimales. En el segundo caso es 2F/3, estas usando 2 como float entre 3, por tanto el resultado es un float, que tiene menos decimales. Si pusieses 2D/3 te daría un double con más decimales.

Para redondear no puedes hacerlo directamente porque double y float son primitivos. Una solución podría ser crear un BigDecimal y utilizar el setScale() para indicarle el número de decimales a utilizar y el modo de redondeo. Por ejemplo para mostar 2D/3 (0.666...) con 5 decimales y redondeando hacia arriba:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2D/3);
bd = bd.setScale(5, RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Por pantalla obtendrías "0.66667"

Comment: Ok. Gracias por responder. Una duda al respecto: System.out.println(1F/12); da 0.083333336. Por qué el 6 del final si tendría que ser un 3?